# Match rest of string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this

```
ch:keyword
ch:test
ch:some_text
```

I need a regular expression which will match all of the strings, however, it must not match the following:

```
ch: (ch: is proceeded by a space, or any number of spaces)
ch: (ch: is proceeded by nothing)
```

I am able to deduce the length of the string with the 'ch:' in it.
Any help would be appreciated; I am using PHP's preg_match()

Edit: I have tried this:

```
preg_match("/^ch:[A-Za-z_0-9]/", $str, $matches)
```

However, this only matches 1 character after the string. I tried putting a * after the closing square bracket, but this matches spaces, which I don't want.

Comment: you might have tried something, could you show it first..!

Comment: Why do you think you need a regular expression? [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) and an `if`-statement would be a more readable approach.

Comment: He needs regular expression because this is what they exist for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^ch:(\S+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

\S+ is for matching 1 or more non-space characters. This should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
^ch:\S.*$
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the easiest way.

Comment: @Kirill: I think this answer is incorrect, as this will match only one non-space character, whereas the requirement is to match a word- you have given \S whereas it should be \S+... check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = <<<TEXT
ch:keyword
ch:test
ch:
ch:some_text
ch: red
TEXT;

preg_match_all('|ch\:(\S+)|', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($matches); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ch:keyword
            [1] => ch:test
            [2] => ch:some_text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword
            [1] => test
            [2] => some_text
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
preg_match('/(?<! +)ch:[^ ].*/', $str);
```